# How to know and load all images in a specific folder?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, c++builder

I have an application (C++ Builder 6.0) that needs to know the total of images there are in a specific folder, and then I have to load them: in an ImageList or in a ComboBoxEx... or any other control...

How can I do that?

I know how to load an image in a control, or to save in a TList, or in an ImageList... but How to know how many files files there are in the directory, and how to load every image in it??

I am Sorry about my English.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084809/windows-thumbnail-frame-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something like this yesterday with C++ using the [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library. However, if you are not using boost already, I would strongly recommend you just use the windows libraries instead. This was my code though in case you're interested:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <set>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

typedef std::vector<fs::path> PathVector;

std::auto_ptr<PathVector> ImagesInFolder(const fs::path& folderPath) {
    std::set<std::string> targetExtensions;
    targetExtensions.insert(".JPG");
    targetExtensions.insert(".BMP");
    targetExtensions.insert(".GIF");
    targetExtensions.insert(".PNG");

    std::auto_ptr<PathVector> paths(new PathVector());

    fs::directory_iterator end;
    for(fs::directory_iterator iter(folderPath); iter != end; ++iter) {
        if(!fs::is_regular_file(iter->status())) { continue; }

        std::string extension = iter->path().extension();
        std::transform(extension.begin(), extension.end(), extension.begin(), ::toupper);
        if(targetExtensions.find(extension) == targetExtensions.end()) { continue; }

        paths->push_back(iter->path());
    }

    return paths;
}
```

This doesn't answer the part of your question about how to actually put the paths into a listbox though.

Comment: to get this to compile I needed to change it to
 std::string extension = iter->path().extension().string();

Answer (score 1):

Use the Win32 functions FindFirstFile and FindNextFile ...?

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical way to identify *every* image in an arbitrary folder. Almost anything you can't identify as something else, could be some sort of image. Then again, using steganography, even something you *can* identify as something else still might be (or contain) at least part of an image as well.

Realistically, you want to pick out a set of formats you want to support, and write code that knows about them. For quite a few purposes, a half dozen formats or so is quite adequate, though the exact half dozen you pick will vary by the type of application -- only a few programs have any use for both bitmapped and vector graphics, for one example.

Once you've decided what you want, `DlgDirList` is probably the easiest way to list some files. If that isn't flexible enough for your purposes, the next obvious choice is `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile`, and `FindClose`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all files in a folder, have a look at the [FindFirst](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FindFirst.html) and FindNext functions in [SysUtils](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils1.html).

Here is an example function which shows how to get a list of files.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::GetDirList(TStrings *List, const AnsiString SearchStr)
{
 TSearchRec SRec;
 AnsiString TempFName;

 List->Clear();

 // start search
 if (FindFirst(SearchStr, faAnyFile, SRec) == 0)
 {
   do
   { 
     if ((SRec.Attr & faDirectory) != faDirectory) // exclude directories
     {
       List->Add(SRec.Name);
     } // end if
   } 
   while (FindNext(SRec) == 0);

   FindClose(SRec);
 } // end if
}
```

**Examples:**
    // get list of all files in directory
    GetDirList(MyStringList, "C:\images*.*");

```
// get list of all .bmp files in directory
GetDirList(MyStringList, "C:\images\*.bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to newer version of C++Builder, have a look at [TMS AdvSmoothImageListBox](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothimagelistbox.asp), from [TMS Software](http://www.tmssoftware.com/).

[image: TMS AdvSmoothImageListBox]

The [TMS Smooth Controls are available free for C++Builder 2010](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27470) users on the from Embarcadero website.

Comment: Credit to the answer given by vcldeveloper on this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084809/windows-thumbnail-frame-view/2084936#2084936